# How can I wait until a view controller is done presenting and dismissed to run next line of code?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I am populating a field called items inside the alertVC, and I need access to that field once the VC has been dismissed. The error that I am getting is that alertVC.item is nil. My guess is that it ran that line before the alertVC was done populating the item field. I have tried this:

```
    @IBAction func addPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let alertVC = entryAlertService.alert()
        present(alertVC, animated: true) {
            self.items.append(alertVC.item!)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

And I have tried this:

```
    @IBAction func addPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let alertVC = entryAlertService.alert()
        present(alertVC, animated: true)
        self.items.append(alertVC.item!)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: I think you are presenting before appending, try the opposite.

Comment: What's happening in alertVC to set `item`? It seems unusual to me you'd be setting a property immediately after presentation.

Comment: You mean that you have a textview in alert, you want text from that view what user write and show in table view?

Comment: Pass a closure to your alert method to be executed when it's finished.

Comment: @AdamPro13, Kazi's comment describes it perfectly

Comment: @KaziAbdullahAlMamun, that is correct

Comment: @Don, Isn't that what I'm doing in the first block of code I posted?

Comment: No, that's the completion handler for the presentation, which will execute immediately after the presentation of the alert is complete. From the docs: "The completion handler is called after the viewDidAppear(_:) method is called on the presented view controller."